# BootstrapValidator não funciona com php rodando no xampp

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, formulário, validação

Estou tentando validar meu formulário com o bootstrapValidator, no PHP porém  o script não roda, mas se eu faço um arquivo html, o arquivo roda.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cadastro de Vagas</title>
<body>
    <?php include("masterpage.php") ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <section>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h2>Cadastro de vagas</h2>
                    </div>

                    <form id="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label"> Cargo: </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Cargo" placeholder="Cargo" />
                                <span class="help-block" id="CargoMsg" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Descricao</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Descricao" placeholder="Descrição" />
                                <span class="help-block DescricaoMsg" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="campoData"> Data final inscrição:</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                                        <input type="text" name="data" id="data"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Efetuar Cadastro</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Limpar formulário</button>
                                </div>                     
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- :form -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            Cargo: {
                container: '#CargoMsg',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Cargo é obrigatório e não pode ser vazio.'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        max: 50,
                        message: 'Cargo tem que ter mais de 3 letras e menos de 50.'
                    }
                }
            },
            Descricao: {
                container: '.DescricaoMsg',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Descrição é obrigatória e não pode ser vazia.'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        max: 5000,
                        message: 'Descrição tem que ter mais de 3 letras e menos de 5000.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Os arquivos js do bootstrap são carregados na página? copiou os mesmos para a pasta do Xampp?

Comment: São e tambem os carrego na masterpage para garantir, e estão  nas pastas do projeto dentro do Xampp

Comment: O endereço chamado no navegador é http://localhost/projeto ou file:///arquivo.php

Comment: o endereço é http://localhost:8080/projeto/view/cadastroVagas.php

Comment: Se o arquivo solto roda a sintaxe está OK. Existe algum outro elemento com `id="form"` na página? Se sim, pode ser isso. Se não for abre o console (`F12` no navegador), recarrega a tela, tenta usar  e posta o que aparece.

Comment: O link que você forneceu é localhost, não é possível acessar ele pela internet, ou seja não temos acesso a ele. Notei que você esqueceu de fechar o HTML com `</html>`. Note .php há conteúdo PHP?